# How to use C# code to create a dynamic background in a UWP applications? (15063)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

We all know that in Web development, you can use JavaScript and Canvas tags to create HTML5 pages with a dynamic background.

For example: [Flat Surface Shader](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/flat-surface-shader/)

I want to know how to use C# code in UWP applications to achieve similar results.

Because of the following code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <Grid></Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This solid color background is too monotonous.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Win2D](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm). It provides a GPU-accelerated XAML canvas control for rendering 2D scenes consisting of thousands of polygons. This canvas control could serve as a background for your page. The library supports custom pixel shaders. You can rely on built-in drawing effects or create your own. Here's the [demo app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/win2d-example-gallery/9nblgggxwt9f).